# Behavior of reports with recordsources and filters set in different locations

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am analyzing a series of reports in an Access database.  Currently, this project is non-functional as the data is in SQL Server and I don't have permissions to it at the moment. Some of the reports have recordsource and filter set programmatically and others are set using the properties -> data tab. One of my colleagues offhandedly mentioned that he thinks report filters may not be applied when the reports are called programmatically if they are set using the properties -> data tab. Of course, he said that and then wandered off and now I'm not sure how to verify this. Is this the case? Can anyone point me to documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague is mistaken.  You can always set the report's RecordSource property, even from a form that might be calling it.  You can use filters in the report's RecordSource simply by adding them to a WHERE clause in the RecordSource.

Answer (score 0):

If a filter string is applied to the report via code as a Filter property, it will be displayed when you view the properties.

This can manually be deleted, modified, or overwritten. Perhaps that's what he had in mind.